# SOAP Client wrong encoding

Tags: php, soap, encoding

Im trying a SOAP Client with PHP. The connection works fine, but the response is always full of questionmarks and new lines (/n).

How i can set utf 8 to my SOAP Connection, or is it possible, so set the response to json?

This is my Code:

```
$c = new SoapClient('https://example.com/services/ShipmentService/V4_3?wsdl');
        $token = [
            'delisId'         => $auth->delisId,
            'authToken'       => $auth->authToken,
            'messageLanguage' => 'de_DE',
        ];
        $header = new SOAPHeader('http://example.com/common/service/types/Authentication/2.0', 'authentication', $token);
        $c->__setSoapHeaders($header);

 $response = $c->storeOrders(...);
```

Comment: can you show us the response you are getting?

Comment: Sure. Response: ```%PDF-1.4
%����
3 0 obj
<</DecodeParms<</Colors 3/Predictor 15/BitsPerComponent 8/Columns 140>>/Type/XObject/ColorSpace/DeviceRGB/Subtype/Image/BitsPerComponent 8/Width 140/Length 1462/Height 140/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
x���nAC��?�"oR�$��ܧE}�9k%*��w�돯.A!�(�B�y�����+�ʣʫ�O���^���0<_�BZ )[���8/�͐�{��|~(B��s�T�%\8�{����9��ٴ�m��k��F7:r�su�@V��vB:!t���F�5��U�FٽE���vBr7O���r��r;����6C"ҧHf�IۉXdwM�[d�^HA�.ɕ�Ld2IT$(ïK�����2H��^̔�w�BS
-�+}R[���@r%���Md����C!-��.....

Comment: response is a pdf data.. you can save it into a file to see the response

Comment: yes, when i save it to a file, the file is damaged, and i cant open the file.

Comment: i found the problem. i think it was base64 decoded, but it wasnt. So all fine now. Thanks